# synchronization text chat with live video stream

Tags: websocket, comments, live-streaming, wowza, ntp

I have a live stream service using wowza. I want to add text chat in it, so viewers could comment about what they watch! The problem is if I use a socket to send comments it wouldn't be synchronized with the correct frame of video. I need help to match the time of video and comments in a correct time. So when viewers replay that VOD, they could see the comments in a right time too. I found some solution like ntp which periscope uses. but I don't know how should I use this.

Answer (score 0):

When you track your comments in the database, just track their timestamps there.  (Database server time, with `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as appropriate for your database server.)  Also track the time at which the video started.  Then build your player to play comments at the right time.

You could even dynamically serve WebVTT if you wanted.